# Turn to String in Python

Tags: python, string, set, tuples

I have created the variable block = {} and mapped a string to it. I think its a set of sets but I'm not sure since i get errors when I'm trying to convert it to a string. when i print it i get
`{(0, 86): ' ', (5, 31): 'e', (3, 35): 'a', (7, 3): 'e', (6, 28): 'o', (4, 36): 'a', (2, 84): ' ', (0, 76): 'b', (5, 57): 'i', (6, 54): ',', (4, 66): ' ', (1, 64): 't', (2, 78): 'c', (0, 98): 'u', (7, 70): ']', (5, 74): 'e', (6, 72): 's', (3, 86): 't', (4, 104): 'f', (1, 122): 'c', (2, 104): 'r', (7, 94): '', (0, 17): 's', (7, 12): 'f', (5, 84): 't', (6, 98): 's', (3, 124): 'i', (4, 118): 't', (1, 28): 'c', (2, 130): 'b', (2, 27): 's', (0, 55): 'o', (5, 126): ' ', (6, 132): 'l', (3, 2): 'g', (0, 128): 'd', (1, 54): 'g', (4, 5): 'a', (2, 53): 'm', (0, 45): ' ', (7, 48): '1', (5, 24): ',', (3, 40): 'n', (1, 40): '.', (6, 23): 'a', (7, 63): '0', (4, 35): 'c', (7, 107): '', (2, 47): 'a', (0, 67): 'e', (7, 25): '.', (5, 34): 'u', (6, 41): 'a', (4, 73): 'A', (1, 89): 'd', (2, 73): 't', (0, 121): 'a', (6, 67): ',', (3, 95): 'e', (4, 87): 'r', (1, 115): 'h', (2, 99): 'A', (5, 93): 'i', (6, 101): 't', (3, 101): 's', (4, 125): 'e', (1, 21): 'g', (7, 42): '3', (2, 18): 'd'......}`

How can i print this as a string? please help

Comment: [What output do you want? What errors do you get when trying? What have you tried so far?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @hlt I want to print it as a string. I dont get errors i just get the output i showed earlier, in a string. I tried map, join, str. for map and join it removes the elements and just prints out the co-oridnates.

Comment: *"just prints out the co-oridnates"* - So the numbers are coordinates. That is important to know, please add stuff like this to your question. Are they `(row, column)` or `(column, row)`?

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces `{}` indicate a dictionary, while the parentheses `()` indicate tuples. What you have is dictionary that maps from tuples (specifically pairs of integers, it would seem, given your example) to strings (specifically strings a single character in length). You need to provide more information about how you intend to print this data (there are many ways to print it), but one example would be as follows:

```
def PrintPointToCharMap(data, row_count=100, col_count=80):
  rows = []
  for row_index in range(row_count):
    rows.add(RowToString(data, row_index, col_count))
  return '\n'.join(rows)

def RowToString(data, row_index, col_count):
  cols = []
  for col_index in range(col_count):
    key = (row_index, col_index)
    char = ' '
    if key in data:
      char = data[key]
    cols.add(char)
   return ''.join(cols)
```

This one is assuming that you are trying to use the dictionary to represent a grid of characters.

Comment: it's not a grid of characters but rather a string, a text file. And the dictionary has different number of cols in each row

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I used nested for loops to iterate through the dictionary and print according to coordinates. Its a bit inefficient but works. Thanks again @hlt and @Michael Aaron Safyan

My code:

```
    (a,b)=max(dictionary)

    string = "String:"

    for i in range (0,a):
        for x in range (0,b):
    string += string.join(dictionary[i,x])        

    print(string)
```